# Disable selecting row or column by clicking the header in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget and I want to disable the behavior that a row or column is selected when you click on a row or column header.

Does anyone know how to disable this behavior?

**Edit:**
The headers need to remain clickable, because the onClick-function is needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
QTableWidget::setSortingEnabled(true);
```

This eliminates the column selection behavior you describe and trades it in for sorting by column!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to disconnect the selectColumn slot from the sectionPressed signal of the header, something along the lines:

```
disconnect(horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionPressed(int)),this, SLOT(selectColumn(int)));
```

Answer (score 2):

`tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);` 
This property holds which selection mode the view operates in. [SelectionMode](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum)

Or maybe you need `tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows )`
This property holds which selection behavior the view uses.
[SelectionBehavior](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionBehavior-enum)

Answer (score 2):

There are several several ways to do it

1. The simple way that is not so good :) (and depends on Qt implementations as everything :):
   in the table view its horizontal header **sectionPressed(int)** is connected to table **selectColumn(int)**, so you can simply disconnect them :( (the same sure for vertical header)
2. You can ipmlement the table view virtual **selectionCommand(const QModelIndex&, const QEvent* event)** interface and return "***no selection***" if event is 0 (as it's a 0 then while clicking on header area)
3. And finally the best and original solution: You can have and then set your own **selectionModels** both for table and its header (or headers) and re implement the selection behaviors as you want.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you can try setting false to the function [setClickable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qheaderview.html#setClickable)</strike>

```
QTableWidget::horizontalHeader()->setClickable(false);
```

If this works, then you can do the same for [verticalHeader][2]

[2]: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#verticalHeader "verticalHeader"

Comment: Hi umar, thank you for the answer. But the header needs to be clickable. I forget to write this.

Comment: self.connect(self.myTableWidget.verticalHeader(), QtCore.SIGNAL('sectionClicked (int)'), self.myFunction)

Comment: try blocking http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qheaderview.html#sectionPressed signal

Comment: I don't know how to block it. Found only blockSignals, but that blocks everything. I disconnected the signal too, but that didn't work neither. Some other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to this question.

```
disconnect(yourTableWidget->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionPressed(int)),yourTableWidget, SLOT(selectColumn(int)));
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
QTableWidgetItem * p_wgtitm = this->ui->tblwSome->item( 0, 0 );
int flags = p_wgtitm->flags();
flags &= ~(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
p_tblitm->setFlags( (Qt::ItemFlags)flags );
```

Answer (score -2):

If Qt for Python is acceptable, it worked for me by doing this:

`def setModel(self, model):
        super().setModel(model)
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionPressed.disconnect()`

Apparently the signal was getting connected in `setModel`. I just disconnected from everything.